# Getting multiple matches for a group in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string `method<arg1,arg2,arg3>`

I would like to use RegEx to get the portions `method`, `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` from this string.

The following regex `/([a-z0-9]+)<(?:([a-z0-9]+),?)*>/i` matches the string as a whole.

That is,

```
var result = /([a-z0-9]+)<(?:([a-z0-9]+),?)*>/i.test('method<arg1,arg2,arg3>');
// result = true
```

But, `regEx.exec` method returns only `method`, `arg3` portions.

```
result = /([a-z0-9]+)<(?:([a-z0-9]+),?)*>/i.exec('method<arg1,arg2,arg3>');

// result is ["methodname<arg1,arg2,arg3>", "methodname", "arg3"]

// as opposed to 
// ["methodname<arg1,arg2,arg3>", "methodname", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
```

Is there a way to get all the matches of a group?

**Note:** I am asking this for the purpose of learning and I do not want a JavaScript work around.

**Edit:** The number of args (arg1, arg2, etc.) is arbitrary and can change in different cases.

Comment: This may help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: Can `method<arg,arg>` appear multiple times in the string?

Comment: +1, good, well formed question

Comment: @techfoobar: thank you. That page cleared the air. It is indeed impossible to capture each arg separately, a limitation of RegEX. Thanks for the info. Post and answer in detail and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
input = "method<arg1,arg2,arg3>";
action = input.match (/^(\w*)\s*<\s*(.*)?\s*>$/);
action[2] = action[2].split (/\s*,\s*/); // array of args

;; processing method action[1] and arguments action[2] (an array)
```

Comment: This is the closest to the answer that I need. @techfoobar's comment in the question explains why it can't be done with a single regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split this up into two expressions, one for the outer string and one for the inner; though, the inner expression can be simplified to just a regular string split.

```
var str = 'method<arg1,arg2,arg3>',
outer_re = /(\w+)<([^>]*)>/g;

while ((match = outer_re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    var fn = match[1],
    args = match[2].split(',');

    console.log(fn, args);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/uyiboc/1/)

Btw, this is able to match multiple method occurrences, e.g.:

```
"method1<arg1> method2<arg1,arg2>"
```

If this is not necessary you can anchor the expression:

```
/^([^<]+)<([^>]*)>$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this regex

`\b([^<]*)<([^,]*),([^,]*),([^>]*)>`

[image]

Captured groups:

```
0: "method<arg1,arg2,arg3>"
1: "method"
2: "arg1"
3: "arg2"
4: "arg3"
```

## Any number of arguments

`\b([^<]*)<([^>]*)>` pulls out the name and all arguments.

[image]

Captured groups:

```
0: "method<arg1,arg2,arg3>"
1: "method"
2: "arg1,arg2,arg3"
```

Then I'd simply split the group 2 on the known delimiter `,`

Comment: While this is correct for 3 arguments, it is not dynamic and won't work if the number of args is unknown.

Comment: I want to know for dynamic number of arguments.

Comment: OP didn't specify that there are multiple arguments

Comment: what is stopping OP from generating this regex via string concatenation such that it accommodates the number of arguments?

Comment: What are you using to generate the rails notation because it looks great!

Comment: @ VoronoiPotato: Thanks. I used debuggex.com which is a bit faster and more realtime then regexper.com. But they both to about the same thing. Really handy for seeing how a regex works.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: The point of having RegEx is to have one pattern match multiple types of input. Changing the pattern each time to match the string kills the purpose of RegEx itself.

Comment: I think you might be being a little purist, a simple easy to understand regex that is used twice is much more valuable than a hard to understand regex that is used once. That being said it looks like there was a good compromise :).